# SQL select with custom ORDER BY data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data `TSA`, `TSB`, `TSC`, `Total`. 
How to display this alphabetically with `Total` always the last one.
Currently I have this and of course it doesn't work.

> select * from table where main_id =x group by col-name asc

Certainly I can't use `desc` because I have another record `ABC`, `BCA`, `CDA`, `Total`.
So how to add "except if col-name is Total"? or perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of hard to be sure with your post (not a lot of detail in there).  But you could probably use a case statement to evaluate your column, and sort on that.  Something like

`case when <your column> = 'Total' then 'ZZZ' else <your column> end as SortKey`
Then you can just order by that new column.

Answer (score 2):

User `order by field`:

```
select * from table 
where main_id =x 
order by FIELD( `col-name`, 'Total' ), t;
```

See:
[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d566/1)

***Refer to***:

1. [MySQL: FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

   - Return the index (position) of the first argument in the subsequent
     arguments.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that.  It looks to be specific to MySQL though.

Comment: This doesn't work because TSA, TSB, TSC are not sorted.

Comment: @JohnRyann: Change as `order by Field( colname, 'total' ), t;`